# La asignacion de miembros especificada no es valida

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, entity-framework

Tengo una tabla donde en una columna anteriormente era varchar pero tuve la necesidad de cambiarlo a VARBINARY donde ahora hay un registro encriptado, eso ya lo tengo no ha problema,
el problema que tengo ahora es que en mi proyecto MVC en C#
cuando actualice mi modelo de Entity F. Me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Error 2019: La asignación de miembros especificada no es válida. El
> tipo
> 'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=100,Unicode=,FixedLength=False]'
> del miembro 'Password' en el tipo 'Empleados.Credenciales' no es
> compatible con
> 'SqlServer.varbinary[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=100,FixedLength=False]'
> del miembro  'Password' en el tipo
> 'Empleados.Store.Credenciales'.   Empleados_Proyect
> C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\Empleados_Proyect\Empleados_Proyect\Models\Auditoria.edmx  203

Deberia de hacer algun tipo de conversion? y Donde?

Comment: entra aqui: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%23/actualizacion-del-modelo-de-marco-de-entidad/1066829102/